# unsatisfied classpath with jogl/applet

Tags: java, applet, classpath, jogl, worldwind

I have a small applet that use Nasa WorldWind and jogl.
If I run it from Netbeans it works but when launched from the browser I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:189)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$000(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:80)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:103)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.access$200(NativeLibLoader.java:49)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader$1.run(NativeLibLoader.java:111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.opengl.impl.NativeLibLoader.loadCore(NativeLibLoader.java:109)
```

This how I embed the applet in the Html , I copied it copied from the Nasa WW applet [example](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/demos/index_applet_fullscreen.html)

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Java Example</Title>
</Head>
    <Body>

<applet code="occ_client_v1.appletLauncher" width="100%", height="100%",
        archive="bigJar.jar,http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/webstart/jogl.jar, http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/webstart/gluegen-rt.jar">
</applet>

</Body>
</Html>
```

I'm stuck with jogl 1.1 beacause WorldWind doesn't support jogl 2 .
Thanks.

Comment: Does JOGL 1.1. have a JNLP (for [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)).

Answer (score 0):

The gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.applet package in the World Wind src has a great example of running as an applet.
http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/tags/1.4.0/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/applet/

I believe the errors you are seeing stem from not having a jogl.jnlp.
The examples point to one at http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/jogl/webstart/jogl.jnlp